SQL Server VLFs marked as active despite no transactions
I've only noticed this issue on our dev environment with databases that have thousands of VLFs (1-4k range) due to abnormal data loads. I understand the recommendation of limiting the number of VLFs, but I am not concerned with best practices. I am more interested in why my VLFs continue to be marked as active despite no long running transactions.
I used sp_WhoIsActive, DBCC OPENTRAN('database'), and system DMVs to prove that there are no sleeping spids/open transactions against my database. When I query log_reuse_wait_desc, I see NOTHING. Even when running a manual CHECKPOINT, nothing seems to happen. The only way I can fix this issue is to remove the database from the AG, adjust it to simple (at which point the VLFs immediately change to inactive), and then backup the log and shrink the file. While this solution is fine for dev/stg, I would like to better understand the issue were it to bubble up to production.
It is also worth mentioning that I attempted to add a 2nd log file, write some records so that it spills over, and then reattempted to CHECKPOINT/Backup/shrink, but to no avail. It only cleared the NEW log file and not the original, at which point I went ahead and dropped the NEW log file to return the database back to its' original state.
Poking around some more and I am wondering if I am encountering "Lazy Log Truncation" issues: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/lazy-log-truncation-or-why-vlfs-might-stay-at-status-2-after-log-clearing/ & https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/coreinfrastructureandsecurityblog/lazy-log-truncation---clearing-of-sql-transaction-log-vlf-status-deferred/370499
However, these articles seem to act as if though this is not an issue, but it is preventing me from shrinking the log files on my primary replica.

I was able to resolve this by the following:

DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'mylog')


Do NOT specify a size here


BACKUP LOG [database] TO DISK='NUL:'


obviously, do not run the above in prod, if you do, specify a path


DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'mylog')


I am not sure if you can specify a size in the final command as I have not tested it, but hopefully this helps someone

